# Does removing the timer make Space Hulk significantly easier?

Tags: house-rules, play-time, space-hulk

I played the recent edition of Space Hulk with my brother, who insisted on playing the entire campaign as the Space Marines (bad idea - they tend to lose!)

He gave up the campaign about half way through, becoming frustrated with his 10 game losing streak.

I thought about how to make it easier. He consistently became distracted by his phone during his (timed) turn, leading to tactical blunders.

**Does removing the timer element make the game much easier, or is it still likely that the space marines will lose?**

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something (haven't played Space Hulk) but... it seems like maybe a few questions are getting mixed up here: (1) is it balanced against Space Marines? (2) if not, does having more time to think address that (i.e. it's actually balanced, the Space Marines are just harder to play)? and (3) how do you make your brother put away his phone?

Comment: Hi @Jefromi. I'm asking (2). I know it's not balanced (1), based on reviews and my own game play. (3) Is very important, but ultimately a question we can't answer - my brother is glued to his phone :-)

Comment: I think your name should be, "Brother of Zombie_Gamer".

Comment: Using the timer puts pressure on the Marine player, much more so if they are using two squads (10 marines) or more. A simple squad (5 Marines, incorporating one sergeant and one flamer) should have time to spare at the beginning of a scenario. If there's a lot of Genestealers to clean up it can get a bit hectic, much more so if Librarians are in play. So yes, no timer does make it easier the more complex the Marine squads are. For an introduction to beginners, I used to play as the Marines with a timer for them to observe game mechanics. When we switched, I would dispense with the timer.

Comment: Unless it's an emergency, put the phone down during your turn. Really, for a 2 player game, you probably should both have your phones down the whole time... Or if you absolutely must check your phone, do it before you start the time, and then wait 3 minutes to check it again (eg after your turn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, removing the timer makes the game significantly easier, almost trivially so.

Why? Because the timer reduces the amount of information the board can yield.

For example, without the timer the marine player can count squares to determine whether it is useful to spend actions putting marines on overwatch/guard. Without the timer, actions are used much more efficiently to achieve the mission objectives and win. With the timer the marine player can be bottled up much easier.